# Aspx, C#, and Authorize.Net Payment Form - How to implement Authorize button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

I am using Visual Studio, c#, and aspx. I have a webform on my page that works fine. Now I want to implement a payment form, which is from Authorize.Net. The code provided from Authorize.Net is the following (I've removed the value just for privacy):

```
<form name="PrePage" method = "post" action = "https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx"> <input type = "hidden" name = "LinkId" value ="VALUEHERE" /> <input type = "submit" value = "Register" /> </form>
```

Essentially I want my submit button to my already-working form to redirect to https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx. This redirect will not work without the value field.

The flow is the person registers on my form, then they are sent to this payment page to pay their registration fee which I am having trouble doing. Afterwards, I'd like for it to redirect to my confirmation page, but I'm not sure how I'll get that to work either.

I know this below can redirect me with C#, but how do I attach the value field?

```
Response.Redirect("https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem and I found this class over Internet years ago

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;


public class remotepost
{
    public remotepost()
    {

    }

    private System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    public string Url = "";
    public string Method = "post";
    public string FormName = "form1";
    public string Msg = "elaburating";

//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    public void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        Inputs.Add(name, value);
    }
//- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    public void Post()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("</head><body onload=\"document.forms[0].submit()\">", FormName));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\">", FormName, Method, Url));

        for(int i=0;i< Inputs.Keys.Count;i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\" >", Inputs.Keys[i], Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]]));
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<p style=\"font-family:Verdana,Arial; font-size:14px; text-align:center;\">{0}</p>",Msg));
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

then use in your buttonclick event as follow

```
remotepost mrp = new remotepost();
mrp.Url = "https://Simplecheckout.authorize.net/payment/CatalogPayment.aspx";
 mrp.Add("LinkId",VALUEHERE);
  mrp.Post();
```